# label/reference isn't working properly

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

I am labelling my first table and then referencing it later, but the number that comes up when I reference it is completely different from the one in the caption. I am expecting Table 1, but I am getting `Table 1.1.` Here are the relevant parts of the table and how I reference the table

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l r r l r c c c c}

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{table:a}
\caption{This is a cool caption}
\end{table}
Table~\ref{table:firstOne}
```

Comment: `\label` must be placed after `\caption`. This way you use some 'random' counter that was increased by `\refstepcounter` before, but not the table counter (which is increased by `\caption`). And `\ref{table:a}` would work better ;-)

Comment: You're welcome. This example was easy to reproduce, but please post full examples of code, not fragments only!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely a section in a `book` class document is labeled instead of the table itself.

`\label` must be placed **after** `\caption`.

Another issue is the wrong label name used for the reference.

If the table counter format should be changed, use `chngcntr` package, for example.

```
\documentclass{book}


\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\section{First section}

\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{l r r l r c c c c}
\end{tabular}
\label{table:a}
\caption{This is a cool caption}

\end{table}

Table~\ref{table:a}  which is actually the section label, but \ref{table:b} is the right label!


\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{l r r l r c c c c}
\end{tabular}

\caption{This is another cool caption}
\label{table:b}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Use `\centering` for having the table centered; the `center` environment would add unwanted space at top and bottom.

Comment: Two `table` environments with nested `center`? *Oh, là, là* `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: I answered quickly ;-) And removed them now